# Retry logic with CompletableFuture

Tags: java, exception, asynchronous, concurrency, java-8

I need to submit a task in an async framework I'm working on, but I need to catch for exceptions, and retry the same task multiple times before "aborting".

The code I'm working with is:

```
int retries = 0;
public CompletableFuture<Result> executeActionAsync() {

    // Execute the action async and get the future
    CompletableFuture<Result> f = executeMycustomActionHere();

    // If the future completes with exception:
    f.exceptionally(ex -> {
        retries++; // Increment the retry count
        if (retries < MAX_RETRIES)
            return executeActionAsync();  // <--- Submit one more time

        // Abort with a null value
        return null;
    });

    // Return the future    
    return f;
}
```

This currently doesn't compile because the return type of the lambda is wrong: it expects a `Result`, but the `executeActionAsync` returns a `CompletableFuture<Result>`.

How can I implement this fully async retry logic?

Comment: Couldn't you simply handle the retry inside `executeMycustomActionHere()`? Maybe just pass a parameter with the number of retries you want.

Comment: @DidierL Sorry I don't get what I should do. I'd simply move the problem inside that function. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, except you would separate the retry from the handling of `CompletableFuture`, which is not really designed for that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think I was successfully. Here's an example class I created and the test code:

---

### RetriableTask.java

```
public class RetriableTask
{
    protected static final int MAX_RETRIES = 10;
    protected int retries = 0;
    protected int n = 0;
    protected CompletableFuture<Integer> future = new CompletableFuture<Integer>();

    public RetriableTask(int number) {
        n = number;
    }

    public CompletableFuture<Integer> executeAsync() {
        // Create a failure within variable timeout
        Duration timeoutInMilliseconds = Duration.ofMillis(1*(int)Math.pow(2, retries));
        CompletableFuture<Integer> timeoutFuture = Utils.failAfter(timeoutInMilliseconds);

        // Create a dummy future and complete only if (n > 5 && retries > 5) so we can test for both completion and timeouts. 
        // In real application this should be a real future
        final CompletableFuture<Integer> taskFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
        if (n > 5 && retries > 5)
            taskFuture.complete(retries * n);

        // Attach the failure future to the task future, and perform a check on completion
        taskFuture.applyToEither(timeoutFuture, Function.identity())
            .whenCompleteAsync((result, exception) -> {
                if (exception == null) {
                    future.complete(result);
                } else {
                    retries++;
                    if (retries >= MAX_RETRIES) {
                        future.completeExceptionally(exception);
                    } else {
                        executeAsync();
                    }
                }
            });

        // Return the future    
        return future;
    }
}
```

---

### Usage

```
int size = 10;
System.out.println("generating...");
List<RetriableTask> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    tasks.add(new RetriableTask(i));
}

System.out.println("issuing...");
List<CompletableFuture<Integer>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    futures.add(tasks.get(i).executeAsync());
}

System.out.println("Waiting...");
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    try {
        CompletableFuture<Integer> future = futures.get(i);
        int result = future.get();
        System.out.println(i + " result is " + result);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(i + " I got exception!");
    }
}
System.out.println("Done waiting...");
```

---

### Output

```
generating...
issuing...
Waiting...
0 I got exception!
1 I got exception!
2 I got exception!
3 I got exception!
4 I got exception!
5 I got exception!
6 result is 36
7 result is 42
8 result is 48
9 result is 54
Done waiting...
```

---

Main idea and some glue code (`failAfter` function) come from [here](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2014/12/asynchronous-timeouts-with.html).

Any other suggestions or improvement are welcome.

Answer (score 40):

Chaining subsequent retries can be straight-forward:

```
public CompletableFuture<Result> executeActionAsync() {
    CompletableFuture<Result> f=executeMycustomActionHere();
    for(int i=0; i<MAX_RETRIES; i++) {
        f=f.exceptionally(t -> executeMycustomActionHere().join());
    }
    return f;
}
```

<sup>*Read about the drawbacks below*</sup>
This simply chains as many retries as intended, as these subsequent stages won’t do anything in the non-exceptional case.

One drawback is that if the first attempt fails immediately, so that `f` is already completed exceptionally when the first `exceptionally` handler is chained, the action will be invoked by the calling thread, removing the asynchronous nature of the request entirely. And generally, `join()` may block a thread (the default executor will start a new compensation thread then, but still, it’s discouraged). Unfortunately, there is neither, an `exceptionallyAsync` or an `exceptionallyCompose` method.

A solution not invoking `join()` would be

```
public CompletableFuture<Result> executeActionAsync() {
    CompletableFuture<Result> f=executeMycustomActionHere();
    for(int i=0; i<MAX_RETRIES; i++) {
        f=f.thenApply(CompletableFuture::completedFuture)
           .exceptionally(t -> executeMycustomActionHere())
           .thenCompose(Function.identity());
    }
    return f;
}
```

demonstrating how involved combining “compose” and an “exceptionally” handler is.

Further, only the last exception will be reported, if all retries failed. A better solution should report the first exception, with subsequent exceptions of the retries added as suppressed exceptions. Such a solution can be build by chaining a recursive call, as hinted by [Gili’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49093420/2711488), however, in order to use this idea for exception handling, we have to use the steps to combine “compose” and “exceptionally” shown above:

```
public CompletableFuture<Result> executeActionAsync() {
    return executeMycustomActionHere()
        .thenApply(CompletableFuture::completedFuture)
        .exceptionally(t -> retry(t, 0))
        .thenCompose(Function.identity());
}
private CompletableFuture<Result> retry(Throwable first, int retry) {
    if(retry >= MAX_RETRIES) return CompletableFuture.failedFuture(first);
    return executeMycustomActionHere()
        .thenApply(CompletableFuture::completedFuture)
        .exceptionally(t -> { first.addSuppressed(t); return retry(first, retry+1); })
        .thenCompose(Function.identity());
}
```

`CompletableFuture.failedFuture` is a Java 9 method, but it would be trivial to add a Java 8 compatible backport to your code if needed:

```
public static <T> CompletableFuture<T> failedFuture(Throwable t) {
    final CompletableFuture<T> cf = new CompletableFuture<>();
    cf.completeExceptionally(t);
    return cf;
}
```

Comment: Note: if you don’t want to report exceptions to the caller, but fall back to `null` value as indicated in the question (though I don’t recommend such coding style), you can simply chain an `.exceptionally(t -> null)` to the resulting future, in either solution.

Comment: If your `whenCompleteAsync()` is run on the same `Executor` as `executeMycustomActionHere()`, I think you could end up with dead-locks because of the `join()` here, as the task will be queued and never get a chance to be executed.

Comment: @Didier L: since no executor has been specified, the default executor will be used. In this case, the underlying Fork/Join framework will start new threads to compensate threads being blocked in `CompletableFuture.join()` (it calls [`ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#managedBlock-java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.ManagedBlocker-) internally). But if you specify an `Executor` explicitly, that is not a `ForkJoinPool`, you’re right.

Comment: The join() may not be acceptable in non-blocking frameworks, regardless of which pool the thread is taken from. A solution without blocking is preferable in that case.

Comment: @tkruse then, `CompletableFuture` and its limited API might not be the right tool for the job. There are other tools in the concurrency API allowing to build much better solutions.

Comment: @tkruse well, one solution is very complicated and involves mutable state, the other solution, added more than a year later, dodges the actual requirement of doing *exception handling*, by assuming that there was a `Response` type having a status code, which makes the task easier but doesn’t solve the OP’s problem. However, that late answer guided me to an actual non-blocking solution to the OP’s task, so it got my upvote now and I updated my answer. I still think that `CompletableFuture` is not the best API for that though. I think, the code of my answer illustrates the point.

Comment: "Unfortunately, there is neither, an exceptionallyAsync or an exceptionallyCompose method." - both were added in Java 12, I'm curious how would you modify your answer based on that? (still wrapping my head on what they actually do)

Answer (score 15):

Instead of implementing your own retry logic, I recommend using a proven library like [failsafe](https://github.com/jhalterman/failsafe#completablefuture-integration), which has built-in support for futures (and seems more popular than [guava-retrying](https://github.com/rholder/guava-retrying)). For your example, it would look something like:

```
private static RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new RetryPolicy()
    .withMaxRetries(MAX_RETRIES);

public CompletableFuture<Result> executeActionAsync() {
    return Failsafe.with(retryPolicy)
        .with(executor)
        .withFallback(null)
        .future(this::executeMycustomActionHere);
}
```

Probably you should avoid `.withFallback(null)` and just have let the returned future's `.get()` method throw the resulting exception so the caller of your method can handle it specifically, but that's a design decision you'll have to make.

Other things to think about include whether you should retry immediately or wait some period of time between attempts, any sort of recursive backoff (useful when you're calling a web service that might be down), and whether there are specific exceptions that aren't worth retrying (e.g. if the parameters to the method are invalid).

Comment: The RetryPolicy constructor syntax has changed slightly, it's now `private static RetryPolicy retryPolicy = RetryPolicy.builder().withMaxRetries(3).build();`

Answer (score 7):

util class:

```
public class RetryUtil {

    public static <R> CompletableFuture<R> retry(Supplier<CompletableFuture<R>> supplier, int maxRetries) {
        CompletableFuture<R> f = supplier.get();
        for(int i=0; i<maxRetries; i++) {
            f=f.thenApply(CompletableFuture::completedFuture)
                .exceptionally(t -> {
                    System.out.println("retry for: "+t.getMessage());
                    return supplier.get();
                })
                .thenCompose(Function.identity());
        }
        return f;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
public CompletableFuture<String> lucky(){
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->{
        double luckNum = Math.random();
        double luckEnough = 0.6;
        if(luckNum < luckEnough){
            throw new RuntimeException("not luck enough: " + luckNum);
        }
        return "I'm lucky: "+luckNum;
    });
}
@Test
public void testRetry(){
    CompletableFuture<String> retry = RetryUtil.retry(this::lucky, 10);
    System.out.println("async check");
    String join = retry.join();
    System.out.println("lucky? "+join);
}
```

output

```
async check
retry for: java.lang.RuntimeException: not luck enough: 0.412296354211683
retry for: java.lang.RuntimeException: not luck enough: 0.4099777199676573
lucky? I'm lucky: 0.8059089479049389
```

Answer (score 6):

I recently solved a similar problem using the [guava-retrying](https://github.com/rholder/guava-retrying) library.

```
Callable<Result> callable = new Callable<Result>() {
    public Result call() throws Exception {
        return executeMycustomActionHere();
    }
};

Retryer<Boolean> retryer = RetryerBuilder.<Result>newBuilder()
        .retryIfResult(Predicates.<Result>isNull())
        .retryIfExceptionOfType(IOException.class)
        .retryIfRuntimeException()
        .withStopStrategy(StopStrategies.stopAfterAttempt(MAX_RETRIES))
        .build();

CompletableFuture.supplyAsync( () -> {
    try {
        retryer.call(callable);
    } catch (RetryException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

Comment: I see no guarantees in the documentation about non-blocking properties of Retryer.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an approach that will work for any `CompletionStage` subclass and does not return a dummy `CompletableFuture` that does nothing more than wait to get updated by other futures.

```
/**
 * Sends a request that may run as many times as necessary.
 *
 * @param request  a supplier initiates an HTTP request
 * @param executor the Executor used to run the request
 * @return the server response
 */
public CompletionStage<Response> asyncRequest(Supplier<CompletionStage<Response>> request, Executor executor)
{
    return retry(request, executor, 0);
}

/**
 * Sends a request that may run as many times as necessary.
 *
 * @param request  a supplier initiates an HTTP request
 * @param executor the Executor used to run the request
 * @param tries    the number of times the operation has been retried
 * @return the server response
 */
private CompletionStage<Response> retry(Supplier<CompletionStage<Response>> request, Executor executor, int tries)
{
    if (tries >= MAX_RETRIES)
        throw new CompletionException(new IOException("Request failed after " + MAX_RETRIES + " tries"));
    return request.get().thenComposeAsync(response ->
    {
        if (response.getStatusInfo().getFamily() != Response.Status.Family.SUCCESSFUL)
            return retry(request, executor, tries + 1);
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(response);
    }, executor);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

maybe it's late but hopes someone might find this useful, I recently solved this problem for retrying rest API call on failure. In my case, I have to retry on 500 HTTP status code, below is my rest client code (we are using WSClient from play framework) you can change it to whatever rest-client as per requirement.

```
 int MAX_RETRY = 3;
 CompletableFuture<WSResponse> future = new CompletableFuture<>();

 private CompletionStage<WSResponse> getWS(Object request,String url, int retry, CompletableFuture future) throws JsonProcessingException {
 ws.url(url)
        .post(Json.parse(mapper.writeValueAsString(request)))
        .whenCompleteAsync((wsResponse, exception) -> {
            if(wsResponse.getStatus() == 500 && retry < MAX_RETRY) {
                try {
                    getWS(request, retry+1, future);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new Exception(e);
                }
            }else {
                future.complete(wsResponse);
            }
        });

     return future;
}
```

This code will return immediately if the status code is 200 or other than 500 whereas if HTTP status is 500 it will retry 3 times.

Comment: This is really simple and useful, but need to handle in case of exception and complete the future or competeExceptionally, if you are completing exceptionally handle exceptionally in usage.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by `theazureshadow`'s answer. His or her answer was great but doesn't work with new version of FailSafe. The below code works with

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>dev.failsafe</groupId>
  <artifactId>failsafe</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

solution:

```
    RetryPolicy<Object> retryPolicy = RetryPolicy.builder()
        .withMaxRetries(MAX_RETRY)
        .withBackoff(INITIAL_DELAY, MAX_DELAY, ChronoUnit.SECONDS)
        .build();
    Fallback<Object> fallback = Fallback.of((AuditEvent) null);

    public CompletableFuture<Object> executeAsync(Runnable asyncTask) {
    return Failsafe.with(fallback)
            .compose(retryPolicy)
            .with(executorService)
            .onFailure(e -> LOG.error(e.getException().getMessage()))
            .getAsync(() -> asyncTask());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We needed to retry a task based on an error condition.

```
public static <T> CompletableFuture<T> retryOnCondition(Supplier<CompletableFuture<T>> supplier,
                                             Predicate<Throwable> retryPredicate, int maxAttempts) {
    if (maxAttempts <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("maxAttempts can't be <= 0");
    }
    return retryOnCondition(supplier, retryPredicate, null, maxAttempts);
}

private static <T> CompletableFuture<T> retryOnCondition(
    Supplier<CompletableFuture<T>> supplier, Predicate<Throwable> retryPredicate,
    Throwable lastError, int attemptsLeft) {

    if (attemptsLeft == 0) {
        return CompletableFuture.failedFuture(lastError);
    }

    return supplier.get()
        .thenApply(CompletableFuture::completedFuture)
        .exceptionally(error -> {
            boolean doRetry = retryPredicate.test(error);
            int attempts = doRetry ? attemptsLeft - 1 : 0;
            return retryOnCondition(supplier, retryPredicate, error, attempts);
        })
        .thenCompose(Function.identity());
}
```

Usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    retryOnCondition(() -> myTask(), e -> {
        //log exception
        return e instanceof MyException;
    }, 3).join();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using resilience4j for this use case. It's very handy!!

Introduction: [resilience4j-retry](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/retry)  and its Javadoc: [Retry](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.github.resilience4j/resilience4j-retry/latest/io/github/resilience4j/retry/Retry.html)

They have method to decorate completionStage directly as below:

```
default <T> java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage<T> executeCompletionStage​(java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService scheduler,
java.util.function.Supplier<java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage<T>> supplier)
```