# Retry request with CompletableFuture Java

Tags: java, java-8, parallel-processing, completable-future, refresh-token

I have a situation where I need to call parallel http requests to get the data.
I have used CompletableFuture to get the data as shown below.

```
Generictype model = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        return lookupService.fetchData(token);
    }, taskExecutor)
```

Problem is I am passing an access token which is of very short period say 60 seconds after that it expires.

If the token expires I need to call another service to get the refresh token and retry the same request with this new token.

How can I handle the situation when the token expires in between parallel calls.

What I am trying to do is when the access token expires it throws an exception of UnAuthorized 401.

I am trying to catch the exception in the exceptionally block of CompletableFuture as shown below.

```
Generictype model = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    return lookupService.fetchData(token);
}, taskExecutor)
   .exceptionally(exception -> {
        String newToken = lookupService.getNewToken(token);
            model = lookupService.fetchData(newToken);
        return model;
    });
```

When I get an exception it enters the exceptionally block but the request is not executed properly.It responds with 302 SAMEORIGIN response.

Is this the correct way to handle this situation or is there any other way so that i can retry the request when access token is expired

Comment: So, the workflow is like this: perform a request with the token -> if token is active, call some service --> if not, get new token and repeat the above steps?

Comment: @Shankha057 Yes, exactly all the calls are executed parallely. If any one request fails i need to get the new token and repeat that request again.

Comment: I think that a different response code than what's excepted shouldn't be treated as an actual error but simply as one of the possible outcomes and as such you can use the `handle` method and check the response and verify if it is valid or not and in such a case, perform retry logic then.

Comment: You can try one of the answers to the question [Retry logic with CompletableFuture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40485398/retry-logic-with-completablefuture), as what you need seems similar.

Comment: @tomkab Thanks I will look into it