# How to write JUnit5 or Mockito test for a retry mechanism built using Supplier<CompletableFuture> as a method param?

Tags: java, java-8, mockito, junit5, completable-future

Have a common framework that isn't server specific which we use to import and re-use objects inside our microservices but can be used for any particular Java program which supports Java 8.

Was tasked to create a `retry()` mechanism that would take the following two parameters:

1. `Supplier<CompletableFuture<R>> supplier`
2. `int numRetries`

What I needed it to do is to make a generic component that conducts a retry operation for a `CompletableFuture` every time there's an exception based on the `numRetries` specified.

Using Java 8, I wrote the following generic helper class which uses a Supplier to retry a method based on a number of retries specified.

Am new to `CompletableFuture`, in general, so am wondering how to write a JUnit 5 (and if Mockito is better) test for this method? Am testing for all edge cases and have made this as generic as possible for others to re-use.

Note this is inside an in-house common framework which is imported by other microservices as a Maven dependency but the aim is to be able to re-use this at the Java SE level.

```
public class RetryUtility {

    private static final Logger log = 
                    LoggerFactory.getLogger(RetryUtility.class);

    public static <R> CompletableFuture<R> retry(
                                       Supplier<CompletableFuture<R>> supplier, 
                                       int numRetries) {
        CompletableFuture<R> completableFuture = supplier.get();
        if (numRetries > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numRetries; i++) {
                completableFuture = 
                            completableFuture
                              .thenApply(CompletableFuture::completedFuture)
                              .exceptionally(
                                  t -> {
                                   log.info("Retrying for {}", t.getMessage());
                                   return supplier.get();
                                })
                              .thenCompose(Function.identity());
            }
        }
        return completableFuture;
    }
}
```

---

Usage: Presume this code compiles and works, I was able to put in a wrong URL in the config file for `client` and `log.info(Error getting orderResponse = {});` was printed twice via `grep` against `app.log` file.

This is the calling class that imports the above class as Maven dependency:

```
public class OrderServiceFuture {

    private CompletableFuture<OrderReponse> getOrderResponse(
                           OrderInput orderInput,BearerToken token) {
        int numRetries = 1;
        CompletableFuture<OrderReponse> orderResponse =
               RetryUtility.retry(() -> makeOrder(orderInput, token), numRetries);
        orderResponse.join();
        return orderResponse;
    }

    public CompletableFuture<OrderReponse> makeOrder() {
        return client.post(orderInput, token),
            orderReponse -> {
            log.info("Got orderReponse = {}", orderReponse);
        },
        throwable -> {
            log.error("Error getting orderResponse = {}", throwable.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

---

Although this example's calling class uses  `OrderSerice` with an `HttpClient` making a call, this is a generic utility class that was specifically written to be reusable for any type of method call which returns `CompletableFuture<OrderReponse>`.

Question(s):

1. How to write a JUnit 5 test case (or Mockito) for this:
   `public static <R> CompletableFuture<R> RetryUtility.retry(Supplier<CompletableFuture<R>> supplier, int numRetries)` method?
2. Is there any edge cases or nuances that someone can see with its design and/or implementation?

Comment: Something in [this direction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40485398/2711488)?

Comment: @Holger - Thanks I changed my question appropriately.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar - need it to test all edge cases(null, number of times, etc) but keep in mind that its generic and reusable for all general purposes involving `CompletableFuture`.

Comment: I used the link from @Holger to come up with this `RetryUtility` but don't see any JUnit tests in that link... Why does this question need to be closed? The Holger link was only asking for the `retry()` implementation but now how to test it... This question is a different question Created the open bounty so someone could help me with some direction using code examples not to tell me that my post should be closed...

Comment: You’ve been long enough to know how stackoverflow works. IMO, your question should be closed because it’s not about a specific problem you encountered while attempting to write JUnit tests. What you’re asking for is someone to write the tests for you, and you’ve shown no evidence that you even tried to do that yourself.

Comment: Am just seeking some direction not a complete solution.

Comment: I'd recommend using a battle tested library like [resilience4j](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/retry) instead of rolling your own. The good thing about it is that someone else will write the tests for you.

Comment: Thank you but this was just supposed to be generic at the Java SE level. I could write the mockito test by injecting my service impl objects but this `RetryUtility` is written inside an in-house common library that is imported into a microservice as a Maven dependency The usage I provided for the `OrderServiceFuture` is from the microservice just as an example. Does this make sense? I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 1):

Before you ask "How do I test method X?" it helps to clarify "What does X actually do?". To answer
this latter question I personally like to rewrite methods in a way such that individual steps become
clearer.

Doing that for your `retry` method, I get:

```java
public static <R> CompletableFuture<R> retry(
        Supplier<CompletableFuture<R>> supplier,
        int numRetries
) {
    CompletableFuture<R> completableFuture = supplier.get();
    for (int i = 0; i < numRetries; i++) {
        Function<R, CompletableFuture<R>> function1 = CompletableFuture::completedFuture;
        CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<R>> tmp1 = completableFuture.thenApply(function1);
        
        Function<Throwable, CompletableFuture<R>> function2 = t -> supplier.get();
        CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<R>> tmp2 = tmp1.exceptionally(function2);
        
        Function<CompletableFuture<R>, CompletableFuture<R>> function3 = Function.identity();
        completableFuture = tmp2.thenCompose(function3);
    }
    return completableFuture;
}
```

Note that I removed the unnecessary `if` statement and also the `log.info` call. The latter isn't
testable unless you pass in a logger instance as a method argument (or make `retry` non-static and
have the logger as an instance variable that is passed via the constructor, or maybe use some
dirty hacks like redirecting the logger output stream).

Now, what does `retry` actually do?

1. It calls `supplier.get()` once and assigns the value to the `completableFuture` variable.
2. If `numRetries <= 0`, then it returns `completableFuture` which is the same CF instance that the
   Supplier's `get` method returned.
3. If `numRetries > 0`, then it does the following steps `numRetries` times:

   1. It creates a function `function1` that returns a completed CF.
   2. It passes `function1` to the `thenApply` method of `completableFuture`, creating a new
      CF `tmp1`.
   3. It creates another function `function2` which is a function that ignores its input argument
      but calls `supplier.get()`.
   4. It passes `function2` to the `exceptionally` method of `tmp1`, creating a new
      CF `tmp2`.
   5. It creates a third function `function3` which is the identity function.
   6. It passes `function3` to the `thenCompose` of `tmp2`, creating a new CF and assigning it to
      the `completableFuture` variable.

Having a clear breakdown of what a function does lets you see what you can test and what you cannot
test and, therefore, might want to refactor. Steps 1. and 2. are very easy to test:

For step 1. you mock a `Supplier` and test that it's `get` method is called:

```java
@Test
void testStep1() { // please use more descriptive names...
    Supplier<CompletableFuture<Object>> mock = Mockito.mock(Supplier.class);
    RetryUtility.retry(mock, 0);
    Mockito.verify(mock).get();
    Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(mock);
}
```

For step 2. you let the supplier return some predefined instance and check that `retry` returns
the same instance:

```java
@Test
void testStep2() {
    CompletableFuture<Object> instance = CompletableFuture.completedFuture("");
    Supplier<CompletableFuture<Object>> supplier = () -> instance;
    CompletableFuture<Object> result = RetryUtility.retry(supplier, 0);
    Assertions.assertSame(instance, result);
}
```

The tricky part is, of course, step 3. The first thing you should look out for is which variables
are influenced by our input arguments. These are: `completableFuture`, `tmp1`, `function2`,
and `tmp2`. In contrast, `function1` and `function3` are practically constants and are not
influenced by our input arguments.

So, how can we influence the listed arguments then? Well, `completableFuture` is the return value
of the `get` method of our `Supplier`. If we let `get` return a mock, we can influence the return
value of `thenApply`. Similarly, if we let `thenApply` return a mock, we can influence the return
value of `expectionally`. We can apply the same logic to `thenCompose` and then test that
our methods have been called the correct amount of times in the correct order:

```java
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(ints = {0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 100})
void testStep3(int numRetries) {
    CompletableFuture<Object> completableFuture = mock(CompletableFuture.class);
    CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<Object>> tmp1 = mock(CompletableFuture.class);
    CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<Object>> tmp2 = mock(CompletableFuture.class);

    doReturn(tmp1).when(completableFuture).thenApply(any(Function.class));
    doReturn(tmp2).when(tmp1).exceptionally(any(Function.class));
    doReturn(completableFuture).when(tmp2).thenCompose(any(Function.class));

    CompletableFuture<Object> retry = RetryUtility.retry(
            () -> completableFuture, // here 'get' returns our mock
            numRetries
    );
    // While we're at it we also test that we get back our initial CF
    Assertions.assertSame(completableFuture, retry);

    InOrder inOrder = Mockito.inOrder(completableFuture, tmp1, tmp2);
    for (int i = 0; i < numRetries; i++) {
        inOrder.verify(completableFuture, times(1)).thenApply(any(Function.class));
        inOrder.verify(tmp1, times(1)).exceptionally(any(Function.class));
        inOrder.verify(tmp2, times(1)).thenCompose(any(Function.class));
    }
    inOrder.verifyNoMoreInteractions();
}
```

What about the method arguments of `thenApply` and `thenCompose`? There is no way to test
that these methods have been called with `function1` and `function3`, respectively, (unless you
refactor your code and move the functions out of that method call) as these functions are local to
our method and not influenced by our arguments.
But what about `function2`? While we cannot test that `exceptionally` is called with `function2` as
an argument, we can test that `function2` calls `supplier.get()` exactly `numRetries` times. When
does it do that? Well, only if the CF fails:

```java
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(ints = {0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 100})
void testStep3_4(int numRetries) {
    CompletableFuture<Object> future = CompletableFuture.failedFuture(new RuntimeException());
    Supplier<CompletableFuture<Object>> supplier = mock(Supplier.class);
    doReturn(future).when(supplier).get();

    Assertions.assertThrows(
            CompletionException.class,
            () -> RetryUtility.retry(supplier, numRetries).join()
    );
    
    // remember: supplier.get() is also called once at the beginning 
    Mockito.verify(supplier, times(numRetries + 1)).get();
    Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(supplier);
}
```

Similarly, you can test that `retry` calls the `get` method `n+1` times by providing a supplier,
that returns a completed future after it has been called `n` times.

What we still need to do (and what we should probably have had done as a first step) is to test
whether the return value of our method behaves correctly:

- If the CF fails `numRetries` tries, the CF should complete exceptionally.
- If the CF fails fewer than `numRetries` tries, the CF should complete normally.

```java
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(ints = {0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 10})
void testFailingCf(int numRetries) {
    RuntimeException exception = new RuntimeException("");
    CompletableFuture<Object> future = CompletableFuture.failedFuture(exception);

    CompletionException completionException = Assertions.assertThrows(
            CompletionException.class,
            () -> RetryUtility.retry(() -> future, numRetries).join()
    );
    Assertions.assertSame(exception, completionException.getCause());
}

@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(ints = {0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 10})
void testSucceedingCf(int numRetries) {
    final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
    final String expected = "expected";

    Supplier<CompletableFuture<Object>> supplier =
            () -> (counter.getAndIncrement() < numRetries / 2)
                    ? CompletableFuture.failedFuture(new RuntimeException())
                    : CompletableFuture.completedFuture(expected);

    Object result = RetryUtility.retry(supplier, numRetries).join();

    Assertions.assertEquals(expected, result);
    Assertions.assertEquals(numRetries / 2 + 1, counter.get());
}
```

Some other cases you might want to consider testing and catching are what happens if `numRetries` is
negative or very large? Should such method calls throw an exception?

---

Another question we haven't touched so far is: ***Is this the right way to test your code?***

Some people might say yes, others
would argue that you shouldn't test the internal structure of your method but only its output given
some input (i.e. basically only the last two tests). That's clearly debatable and, like most things,
depends
on your requirements. (For example, would you test the internal structure of some sorting
algorithm, like array assignments and what not?).

As you can see, by testing the internal structure, the tests become quite complicated and involve a
lot of mocking. Testing the internal structure can also make refactoring more troublesome, as your
tests might start to fail, even though you haven't changed the logic of your method. Personally, in
most situations I wouldn't write such tests. However, if a lot of people depended on the correctness
of my code, for example on the order in which steps are executed, I might consider it.

In any case, if you choose to go that route, I hope these examples are useful to you.