# Spring Integration - Asynchronous handler method with retry functionality

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

What is the correct way to define an asynchronous handler method when using Spring Integration flows?

For example, say I have the following configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(5);
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        taskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("task-thread-");
        return taskExecutor;
    }

    @Bean
    public PollerSpec poller() {
        return Pollers.fixedRate(100).taskExecutor(taskExecutor());
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageBuilderFactory messageBuilderFactory() {
        return new DefaultMessageBuilderFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public TestMessageProducer testMessageProducer(MessageBuilderFactory messageBuilderFactory) {
        return new TestMessageProducer(messageBuilderFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel processChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.queue(1000).get();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel responseChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.direct().get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow inputFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
            .from(testMessageProducer(messageBuilderFactory()))
            .channel(processChannel())
            .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow processFlow(MessageHandler handler) {
        return IntegrationFlows
            .from(processChannel())
            .bridge(e -> e.poller(poller()))
            .handle(handler, "process")
            .channel(responseChannel())
            .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow responseFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
            .from(responseChannel())
            .handle(msg -> {
                log.info("Received response: {}", msg.getPayload());
            })
            .get();
    }
}
```

with a synchronous `MessageHandler` that looks like:

```
@Component
public class MessageHandler {
    
    public String process(String input) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(1000); // Simulating a long-running task.
        System.out.println("Processing: " + input);
        return input.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

If I were to change the `MessageHandler` implementation to be asynchronous:

```
@Component
public class MessageHandler {

    public CompletableFuture<String> process(String input) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                System.out.println("Processing: " + input);
                Thread.sleep(1000); // Simulating a long-running task.
                return input.toUpperCase();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new CompletionException(e);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

then I get the following output:

```
...
Received response: java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@4d191bf[Not completed]
```

I tried an alternative approach where I changed the `MessageHandler` to send messages back to the response-channel after it processed it:

```
@Component
public class MessageHandler {

    private final MessageChannel responseChannel;

    public MessageHandler(MessageChannel responseChannel) {
        this.responseChannel = responseChannel;
    }

    public void process(Message<String> inputMessage) {
        String input = inputMessage.getPayload();
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            try {
                System.out.println("Processing: " + input);
                Thread.sleep(1000); // Simulating a long-running task.
                String result = input.toUpperCase();
                responseChannel.send(MessageBuilder.createMessage(result, inputMessage.getHeaders()));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new CompletionException(e);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

To get this to work I needed to remove the `channel(responseChannel())` line from the `processFlow()` configuration method. However, I'm not sure that this is the correct way to do it. I've also noticed that if I use a `RetryOperationsInterceptor` for the handler's `process` method:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow processFlow(MessageHandler handler, RetryOperationsInterceptor retryInterceptor) {
    return IntegrationFlows
        .from(processChannel())
        .bridge(e -> e.poller(poller()))
        .handle(handler, "process", e -> e.advice(retryInterceptor))
        .channel(responseChannel())
        .get();
}
```

then any exceptions that are thrown inside the future won't result in the `process` method getting retried.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I got it working to an extent.

I changed the `MessageHandler` to return a Spring `ListenableFuture`:

```
@Component
public class MessageHandler {

    public ListenableFuture<String> process(Message<String> inputMessage) {
        String input = inputMessage.getPayload();
        return new CompletableToListenableFutureAdapter<>(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                System.out.println("Processing: " + input);
                Thread.sleep(1000); // Simulating a long-running task.
                return input.toUpperCase();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new CompletionException(e);
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

and I also had to change the configuration for the process-flow by specifying that the handler method is async:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow processFlow(MessageHandler handler) {
    return IntegrationFlows
        .from(processChannel())
        .bridge(e -> e.poller(poller()))
        .handle(handler, "process", e -> e.async(true))
        .channel(responseChannel())
        .get();
}
```

The result of this is that the responses are correctly printed out in the handler that is defined in the `responseFlow` method.

However, I still have an issue where if an exception occurs in the handler method's future then the retry-advice is ignored. Thus, if I specify a `RetryOperationsInterceptor` bean in the configuration and change the `processFlow` to use this interceptor as follows:

```
@Bean
public RetryOperationsInterceptor retryInterceptor() {
    Map<Class<? extends Throwable>, Boolean> retryableExceptions = new HashMap<>();
    retryableExceptions.put(MyCustomRetryableException.class, true);
    return RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateless()
        .retryPolicy(new SimpleRetryPolicy(5, retryableExceptions, true))
        .backOffOptions(500, 2.0, 10000)
        .build();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow processFlow(MessageHandler handler, RetryOperationsInterceptor retryInterceptor) {
    return IntegrationFlows
        .from(processChannel())
        .bridge(e -> e.poller(poller()))
        .handle(handler, "process", e -> e.advice(retryInterceptor).async(true))
        .channel(responseChannel())
        .get();
}
```

and the `MessageHandler` is changed to:

```
@Component
public class MessageHandler {

    public ListenableFuture<String> process(Message<String> inputMessage) {
        String input = inputMessage.getPayload();
        return new CompletableToListenableFutureAdapter<>(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                System.out.println("Processing: " + input);
                if (input.equals("Input:0")) {
                    throw new MyCustomRetryableException();
                }
                Thread.sleep(1000); // Simulating a long-running task.
                return input.toUpperCase();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new CompletionException(e);
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

then I can see from the output that the `process` method is not called multiple times for the input-string `Input:0`. I only see the exception being printed out once.

**Edit:** In case anyone stumbles across this and wants to know how to do the asynchronous retrying. According to @ArtemBilan (see the comments below) the `RetryOperationsInterceptor` will only work for blocking (or synchronous) handler methods. If you want to have your asynchronous handler methods retry on certain exceptions you can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40485398/retry-logic-with-completablefuture) post for some inspiration. I made use of [resilience4j](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j) to get it to work. I basically had to add the following to my configuration class:

```
@Bean
public RetryConfig retryConfig() {
    return RetryConfig.custom()
        .retryExceptions(MyCustomRetryableException.class)
        .maxAttempts(3)
        .build();
}

@Bean
public Retry handlerRetry() {
    return Retry.of("handler-retry", retryConfig());
}

@Bean
public ScheduledExecutorService retryScheduler() {
    return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
}
```

and then I changed the `MessageHandler` to look like:

```
@Component
public class MessageHandler {

    private final Retry handlerRetry;
    private final ScheduledExecutorService retryScheduler;

    public MessageHandler(Retry handlerRetry, ScheduledExecutorService retryScheduler) {
        this.handlerRetry = handlerRetry;
        this.retryScheduler = retryScheduler;
    }

    public ListenableFuture<String> process(Message<String> inputMessage) {
        String input = inputMessage.getPayload();
        AtomicLong retryCounter = new AtomicLong(0L);
        CompletableFuture<String> retryingFuture = handlerRetry
            .executeCompletionStage(retryScheduler, () -> doWork(input, retryCounter))
            .toCompletableFuture();
        return new CompletableToListenableFutureAdapter<>(retryingFuture);
    }

    private CompletableFuture<String> doWork(String input, AtomicLong retryCounter) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                long attempt = retryCounter.getAndIncrement();
                if (attempt == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Processing: {}", input);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Processing: {}, retry-attempt: {}", input, attempt);
                }
                if (input.equals("Input:0")) {
                    throw new MyCustomRetryableException();
                }
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                return input.toUpperCase();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new CompletionException(e);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You'll see that when you run the code it will retry the body of the future that the `doWork()` method returns for the case where the string is equal to `Input:0`

Comment: That's correct. This is really has nothing to do with a `Future` failure. The retry advice is applied on a `process()` method, not the `Future` completion and so. In other words this `RetryOperationsInterceptor` is for blocking methods, not async. There is no async retry feature: you have to do it yourself on the returned `Future` or convert it into a Reactor `Mono` an do retry over there.

Comment: @ArtemBilan, ah, ok. Thanks. I'll do the retry in the ```Future``` then.